# javascript search in array list of hashes

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

a like search a element in next array:

```
var x = new Array();
x['op1'] = { 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2' };
x['op2'] = { 'a' => '3', 'b' => '4' };
```

I need to rescue the hash that matches the array name. For example:

Input: op1

Output: { 'a' => '3', 'b' => '4' }

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Not clear what you want - please give an example input and output

Comment: What you've written isn't even valid Javascript syntax for an array or object.

Comment: Arrays are like `[1, 2, 3]`, objects are like `{key: value, key: value, key: value}`

Comment: You want a structure like `var foo = {option1: { a: 1, b: 2 }, option2: { a: 3, b: 4 }}`

Comment: It looks like you want `arrlist` to actually be an object with keys `option1`, etc. Otherwise your code makes no sense. You should rewrite it with code that when copies and pasted into a javascript interpreter isn't a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is simply an object containing other objects. This way you can reference them by name, like so:

```js
var obj = {
  'option1': { 'a': '1', 'b': '2' },
  'option2':{ 'a': '3', 'b':'4' }
};

function getProp(propName) {
  return obj[propName];
}

console.log(getProp("option2"));
```